# How to invoke FirstOrDefault(customPredicate) function with Reflection

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

Ive been researching on this but it seems to be a complicated topic. Im using reflection to be able to dynamically call the method "FirstOrDefault" from my _dbContext.Table
This is the line I need make dynamic:

```
var tableObject = _dbContext.Table.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 332)
```

This is the code snippet of my solution so far:

```
    var contextType = _dbContext.GetType();
    var contextTableReference = contextType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Contains(tableName));
    var tableInstance = GetInstanceOfTable(tableName);
    var tableType = tableInstance.GetType();
    var contextTableMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Contains("FirstOrDefault"));
    var DbSetOfT = contextTableReference.GetValue(_dbContext);

    var col = "PersonId";
    var val = 332;

        
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(tableType, "x");

    MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, col);
    ConstantExpression rightSide = Expression.Constant(val);
    BinaryExpression operation = Expression.Equal(property, rightSide);
    Type delegateType = typeof (Func<,>).MakeGenericType(tableType, typeof (bool));
    LambdaExpression predicate  = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, operation, parameter);
        
    //Contains the reference to the First or Default method from the Queryable class  
    
    MethodInfo genericMethod = contextTableMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { tableType});
        
    object retVal = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {DbSetOfT, predicate});
```

Here is my helper function to create an instance of a given object type

```
    private readonly string FullyQualifiedAssemblyName = "DBManager.Models.@, DBManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";

    internal object GetInstanceOfTable(string tableName)
    {         
        Type t = Type.GetType(GetFullAssemblyNameForTable(tableName)); 
    
        return Activator.CreateInstance(t);          
    }

    internal string GetFullAssemblyNameForTable(string tableName)
    {
        return FullyQualifiedAssemblyName.Replace("@", tableName);
    }
```

My issue is when i try to invoke the method:

```
    object retVal = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {DbSetOfT , predicate});
```

It throws the error:

> System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'DBManager.Models.Table' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[DBManager.Models.Table]'.

Im thinking that I might be invoking the method with incorrect parameters.

Here is the post I found while investigating:
[How to Invoke IDBSet.FirstOrDefault(predicate) using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502088/how-to-invoke-idbsett-firstordefaultpredicate-using-reflection)

### UPDATE

I implemented the solution suggested by David and cleaned up some unnecessary code:

```
     var DbSetOfT = contextTableReference.GetValue(_dbContext);
     object retVal = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {DbSetOfT, predicate});
```

and Im getting a new error

> System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1`1[System.Func`2[DBManager.Models.Table,System.Boolean]]' cannot be converted to type 'DBManager.Models.Table'.

Comment: Are you always comparing `.Id`? Then just define an interface and use generics. There are 4 `Queryable.FirstOrDefault` methods, I think you're trying to call `.FirstOrDefault(TSource)` you'll need to test the number and type of parameters.

Comment: I dont know what Im comparing the values against since the tables,columns and values are provided dynamically

Comment: The easiest way to identify the correct method is via `new Func<...signature..>(Queryable.FirstOrDefault).Method`

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a `TTable` instance instead of a `IQueryable<TTable>` to `genericMethodInvoke..  Try something like:

```
var DbSetOfT = contextTableReference.GetValue(_dbContext);
object retVal = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {DbSetOfT , predicate});
```

Also this

```
var contextTableReferenceType = contextTableReference.GetType();
```

is wrong, as it's going to return a `typeof(PropertyInfo)`.  In general all that reflection code is a mess and needs to be reworked.

Comment: Appreciate the response, I cleaned up a bit the code and implemented your suggestion but im getting another error: